# Different border with title text and transparent background

Tags: html, css, background, border

I want to create a box like this  with random text title:  http://oi44.tinypic.com/1tu4xz.jpg

I know how to code this with static (unchanged) text, but k dont know how to do this effective with random variable-length text and border. It is important to let the background show through.

Please, do you know something? It may just be a reference to a similar solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try playing with `fieldset` and `legend` elements. They are usually used in forms, however they could certainly offer an easy solution ... to achieving what you want here.

You could try something like this:

```
 <fieldset>
     <legend>Title text</legend>
     <p>Your random content ;-)</p>
 </fieldset>
```

and in your CSS something like this:

```
  legend {
      text-align:center;
      padding:0 20px;
  }
  fieldset {
      border:2px dotted #000;
  }
```

you can see the body background through the legend and the border.

[here is a jsfiddle to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/2nKP2/) (it uses a border image as an additional example).

Comment: Since you want to do some fancy borders  ... here is a good article on the border-image property: http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

Answer (score 0):

Create a normal box with a frame, like:

```
<div style="border:1px solid black"></div>
```

Then insert an element OVER the box with your title, background-color: white and some paddings. Then this element will cover the part of the border.

Of course you can set some background image for the title element instead of white color- it will work too.

Comment: Thank you for answer.

I have to keep the PSD of graphic designer. The problem that the length of the text and background-color/image will change...